# What are all the things that Mark Cooper-Jones think look like a wizard?

Tags: continuity

[Early in the 2021 popular science video “The mystery of the squarest country” by the Map men Jay Foreman and Mark Cooper-Jones has this exchange:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mrNEVUuZdk&t=13s)

> Jay: Bangladesh?
>
> Mark: No, Bangladesh looks like a wizard.
>
> Jay: You think everything looks like a wizard.
>
> Mark: <shrug>

However, so far I've only found one other case of Mark saying that something looks like a wizard.  That is [almost at the end of a 2016 video about Berlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwprznh3d-o&t=151s) where Mark has drawn a wizard to the blank are left by West Berlin.

I expect the 2021 video made this joke because the video series has shown Mark compare other blobs to a wizard.  But so far I haven't been able to find any other.  So what other blobs does Mark think look like a wizard?

Comment: I don't know the video series in question but how does it relate to literature?

Comment: @MattThrower I am hoping that in the broad definition of literature that our site is using, the series itself counts as literature, and questions about it will be on topic, at least if I ask about narrative elements rather than production techniques specific to videos.  I know this might be controversial but I prefer that we find out the site scope together experimentally, rather than just refrain to post questions that may be found off topic.

Comment: This question is perhaps more suited for [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), no?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about literature as our site defines it. We tend to focus on written works. When we do entertain questions about performed works (movies, tv, opera, plays), they appear to be about the relationship between those shows and their written counterparts (novelizations/screenplay/original book/script/libretto). Perhaps a meta question could be asked about the suitability of this question for this site, but for now I'm voting to close.

Comment: To quote [the help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "We interpret ‘literature’ in a broad sense, including written, spoken and sung works, in all genres, languages and forms: poetry, plays, stories, novels, lyrics, comic books, essays, belles-lettres, and so on." That list does include works with visual components that form an integral part of the experience (i.e. plays and comic books); on the other hand, it conspicuously excludes movies/TV shows/videos. So I would say that videos are out of scope _at the current time_, but there is room for debate going forward.

Comment: @verbose: I asked a meta question: https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/can-questions-about-a-movie-tv-show-video-be-on-topic-if-so-which-ones

Answer (score 1):

The way to answer this question is to extract the transcript for each episode of the program and search it for “wizard”. This will tell you whether Jay’s line quoted in the question was based on Mark’s dialogue in previous episodes, or whether it was a joke with no basis in the previous episodes.

The transcript of a YouTube video can be accessed by clicking on the three dots at the end of the row of buttons below the video, and selecting “Show transcript” from the drop-down menu.

[image]

The transcript appears in its own window on the right, where it can be copy-pasted or searched.

[image]

Simply repeat for all episodes of the program and you will have your answer.

There are ways to automate this process, for example [`yt-fts`](https://github.com/NotJoeMartinez/yt-fts) is a Python script that scrapes the transcript for all videos in a channel.